# extract dots from curves

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, curves

I have a black and white picture of curves and I want to extract minimum dots representing each curve. dots are connected by straight lines. this is an example of what I want:

[image]
[image]

It is useful If I could know the precedence of dots especially in tied sections. I'm using c++ and opencv. 
What algorithms I should use for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV provides nice and simple function for this `cv::approxPolyDP`.

```
void approxPolyDP(InputArray curve, OutputArray approxCurve, double epsilon, bool closed)
```

**A simple example:**

```
std::vector<cv::Point> curve;
//fill curve
std::vector<cv::Point> approximated_polyline;
cv::approxPolyDP(Mat(curve), approximated_polyline, 3, false);
```

Comment: but I don't have curve points. I used this method with my picture and it gave me exception at memory location.

Comment: if you suggest an algorithm for that I would appreciate it. because I need some modification on it I need it to write myself.

Comment: You apply contouring to get the points curve. but self intersection contours would be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Key point detection algorithms should be of help. [This page](http://web.cs.sunyit.edu/~poissad/projects/Curve/about_project.php) provides a brief history and opens up a wide array of literature to read and experiment. It might also be worthwhile to refer [this](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~roppeth/courses/7970%202015A%20AdvMobRob%20sp15/literature/%5B2008%5D%20Local%20Invariant%20Feature%20Detectors-%20A%20Survey.pdf) survey on local invariant feature detectors.